# Fibonacci function from book "The Book of R"

Tags: r, sequence, fibonacci

What modification is needed so function returns a sequence without the number 1 duplicated?

```
myfib<- function(){
        fib.a<-1
        fib.b<- 1
        cat(fib.a,", ",fib.b,",",sep="")
        repeat{
                temp<- fib.a+fib.b
                fib.a<-fib.b
                fib.b<-temp
                cat(fib.b,", ", sep="")
                if(fib.b>150){
                        cat("BREAK NOW...")
                        break
                }
        }
}
```

instead of 
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, BREAK NOW...

return 
1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, BREAK NOW...

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The Fibonacci sequence is supposed to begin `1, 1, ...` (or in some representations, `0, 1, 1, ...`).

Comment: Really?? I was about to answer, until I saw that *you are explicitly `cat`ing the first 1*. Just change your first output using `cat`. (I agree with neilfws, though, calling it "the Fibonacci sequence" and omitting that first "1" is inaccurate. And for the record, this function returns nothing, so your question "returns a sequence" is just wrong.)

Comment: Shouldn't the `4` in your lists be `5`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first number from your `cat`:

```
myfib <- function() {
    fib.a <- 1
    fib.b <- 1
    cat(fib.b, ", ", sep="")
    repeat {
        temp <- fib.a + fib.b
        fib.a <- fib.b
        fib.b <- temp
        cat(fib.b, ", ", sep="")
        if(fib.b > 150) {
            cat("BREAK NOW...")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Or change the initial values:

```
myfib <- function() {
    fib.a <- 1
    fib.b <- 2
    cat(fib.a, ", ", fib.b, ", ", sep="")
    repeat {
        temp <- fib.a + fib.b
        fib.a <- fib.b
        fib.b <- temp
        cat(fib.b, ", ", sep="")
        if(fib.b > 150) {
            cat("BREAK NOW...")
            break
        }
    }
}
```