# Append to end of vector

Tags: r, vector, append

I'm new to R. How to append to the end of a returned vector once function hits threshold?

```
myfib3 <- function(thresh){
        fibseq <- c(1,1)
        counter <- 2
        repeat{
                fibseq <- c(fibseq,fibseq[counter-1]+fibseq[counter])
                counter <- counter+1
                if(fibseq[counter]>thresh){
                        #cat("BREAK NOW...")
                        break
                }
                        }
        return(fibseq)
}


myfib3(150) 
[1]   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21  34  55  89 144 233
```

I want

> [1]   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21  34  55  89 144 233 BREAK NOW...

Comment: Are you asking for the literal `character` string of "BREAK NOW" to be appended to the `integer` vector of (interrupted) Fibonacci sequence? I'm not sure why this would be useful or desired ...

Comment: Do you mean `fibseq <- c(fibseq , "BREAK NOW...")`? And what r2evans said!

Comment: (Since you're new to R, you may not realize ... doing so will convert all integers in the vector to their `character` representation, probably not what you want/need.)

Comment: Compare with [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46534924/4752675)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfib3 <- function(thresh){
        fibseq <- c(1,1)
        counter <- 2
        repeat{
                fibseq <- c(fibseq,fibseq[counter-1]+fibseq[counter])
                counter <- counter+1
                if(fibseq[counter]>thresh){
                        #cat("BREAK NOW...")
                        break
                }
                        }
        return(cat(as.character(fibseq), "BREAK NOW..."))
}
```

Comment: Is the datatype conversion needed because it's concatenating a vector, and requires same datatype for all elements?

Comment: You should be able to simply: return(cat(fibseq, "BREAK NOW...")) but I was making the point that you need the two to be of the same type for the way you are returning it, as a single vector, R automatically coerces the two types into one, of type character. There are other ways to return data from a function, e.g., list with one element holding the data, the other element having "BREAK NOW..." but you haven't explained what you specifically want.

Comment: @ssp3nc34 You answered just as I hoped.  I'm in learning stage trying to understand why things work one way and not another. I didn't realize R coerced it behind scenes. Good to make explicit. Thank you.

Comment: @Aitch, you're welcome and welcome to SO. If I've answered your question, please mark it answered so the question can be closed.

Comment: @ssp3nc34  I voted up your answer but  got a pop up to the effect of "Thanks.  Votes by posters having less than 15 reputation are recorded but are not reflected in publicly posted score"